# Can't run Flink in Standalone Kubernetes mode with JobManager HA

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I'm running Apache Flink in Standalone Kubernetes (sesion) mode without Job Manager HA. But I need to deploy Job Manager HA, because only in HA mode, Flink can be persistent (can save job's after job manager restart).
Flink runs in dedicated kubernetes namespace, and I have permissions only to namespace.

HA are enabled using this article:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/ha/kubernetes_ha/

and I use yaml files from this article:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#kubernetes-high-availability-services

I have for example k28s namespace named flink-namespace. In this namespace I've created:

- serviceAccount named flink-sa
- role witch permissions to create/edit Configmaps in this namespace

so this serviceAccount has permissions to create/editr configmaps, but only in this namespace.

After deployment, jobManager can't start and throws error:

*Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: configmaps "flink-restserver-leader" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:flink-namespace:flink-sa" cannot watch resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "default"*

With mean that serviceAccount with Flink are using to manage Configmaps, try to create Configmap in namespace "default" not in namespace "flink-namespace"

Does anybody know how to config flink to manage configmaps in specified namespace ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - possibility to tell Flink in with kubernetes namespace is running I found in Flink source code.
So, to solve this problem you should set this in config:

*kubernetes.namespace: YOUR_NAMESPACE_NAME*